# vue test utils mount option data not working with compostion api

Tags: vue.js, vue-test-utils

When i am learning the vue-test-utils from the offical site [conditional-rendering](https://next.vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/conditional-rendering.html#using-data).

I tried to change the *option api* to *composition api*.
It seems like the mount option data not working with the *composition api*.
[image]

Nav.vue **Composition API** **test FAIL**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <a id="profile" href="/profile">My Profile</a>
    <a v-if="admin" id="admin" href="/admin">Admin</a>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref } from 'vue'

const admin = ref(false)
</script>
```

Nav.vue **Option API** **test PASS**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <a id="profile" href="/profile">My Profile</a>
    <a v-if="admin" id="admin" href="/admin">Admin</a>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      admin: false,
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

Nav.spec.js **test**

```js
test('renders an admin link', () => {
  const wrapper = mount(Nav, {
    data() {
      return {
        admin: true
      }
    }
  })

  // Again, by using `get()` we are implicitly asserting that
  // the element exists.
  expect(wrapper.get('#admin').text()).toEqual('Admin')
})
```

Comment: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-test-utils-next/issues/228#issuecomment-716086264
mount option data and setData function seems not compatible  to compostion api

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution but I don't know if it's a good solution

```
test("renders an admin link", async () => {
   const wrapper = mount(Nav);
   wrapper.vm.admin = true;
   await nextTick();

   expect(wrapper.get("#admin").text()).toEqual("Admin");
});
```